# How can I change the Start Automatically setting in IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, iis-8

I have a problem with a web site running on an IIS 8.5 server that is not started automatically when the server reboots. The site is originally installed through ServerManager, where there is this line of code:

> site.ServerAutoStart = false;

Now I would like to change this setting through the IIS Manager interface.

In IIS 7.5 i can set a web site to start automatically by setting the Start Automatically property under Advanced settings. But this setting is gone in IIS 8.5.

Comment: I solved my concrete problem by making a small console program that changed the setting in c# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem inspired by this question:

[How to config application pool in IIS 7.5 automatically re-start when it was stopped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280886/how-to-config-application-pool-in-iis-7-5-automatically-re-start-when-it-was-sto)

It is possible to access and edit all the detailed settings through the Configuration Editor, which can be accessed through the Features View in IIS Manager. I realize that in the link Mr Mo sent, the Configuration Editor was used, but it is not specified very clearly how to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2014/01/07/configure-the-iis-application-initialization-module.aspx

I think it will solve the issue.

Comment: This solves an other problem with keeping the server warm. My problem is that the site does not start at all after a reboot. And I cannot find a setting to change this.

Comment: you need to set `applicationDefaults.preloadEnabled` to `true`. You can also find this setting under the Advanced Settings... link in IIS for the website in question.