# How to set IIS connection time out to infinity or making it re-start automatically after 1740 minutes

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7

I am working on an Embedded Project where I pass RGB (hexa) values to serial port  continuously and i have hosted the application on IIS.

But as IIS App Pool worker.exe gets stopped after 1740 minutes , i get an error as it has stopped working .

Can i make App Pool to run forever or if i make it re-start automatically through App Settings ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes you can, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280886/how-to-config-application-pool-in-iis-7-5-automatically-re-start-when-it-was-sto

Comment: By keeping Start Mode to "Always Running " will keep my IIS restart and not stopped at anytime