# Disable IIS App pool. Possible?

Tags: iis

Just like disabling windows service, is there a way to disable app pool in IIS? This is just to prevent apppool restarting on server restart.

Comment: What does this have to do at all with [tag:c#]/[tag:web-services]/[tag:rest]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This C# example works for me

```
string appPoolPath = "IIS://localhost/W3SVC/AppPools/myapppool";
            var appPool = new DirectoryEntry(appPoolPath);
            appPool.Invoke("Start", null);
            appPool.Invoke("Stop", null);
            appPool.Invoke("Recycle", null);`
```

Answer (score 0):

In IIS Manager there is the "Start Automatically" setting in the (General) area in Advanced Settings.

Also see [How to config application pool in IIS 7.5 automatically re-start when it was stopped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280886/how-to-config-application-pool-in-iis-7-5-automatically-re-start-when-it-was-sto) for an alternative way to do the same thing.